# boost::barrier object lifetime — should it be kept alive after all threads reach wait()?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, boost, boost-thread

Consider the following:

```
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

boost::thread spawn() {
    boost::barrier barrier{2};
    boost::thread ret{[&barrier] {
        // some initialization code  
        barrier.wait();
        // actual thread code
    }};

    barrier.wait();
    return ret;
}
```

The `spawn` function creates a `boost::barrier` object on the stack, spawns a new thread and then waits until it reaches the barrier. The purpose is that `spawn` function wants to wait until the spawned thread has been actually started and initialized before returning control.

After the new thread reaches the barrier, the `spawn` function resumes, destroys the barrier object and returns. Looks quite neat.

Is the presented approach safe? If not, what is the recommended way to achieve the desired behaviour? (I guess I could keep the barrier under `shared_ptr` but that somehow doesn't feel like the right way.)

---

I see a possible problematic case:

1. main thread calls `wait`
2. spawned thread calls `wait` and wakes other threads (but the `wait` function does not finishes its job)
3. parent thread wakes from `wait` and destroys the barrier
4. spawned thread does some other things in `wait` (eg. looking for completion function) that can crash because they operate on the barrier object that was deleted

So the question likely boils down to whether `wait` can be treated "atomically" (ie. it won't touch the barrier after threads are waked up) — unless I missed some other risks?

The [Boost documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.barriers.barrier.member_function__wait___) says:

> When the count-th thread calls wait, the barrier is reset and all waiting threads are unblocked.

I'd say that the wording suggests that the barrier is touched first and only after that threads are unblocked — or is it just an unreliable overinterpretation?